# Tree image layout in CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, layout, tree, image-scaling

I wish to arrange images in a tree hierarchy, with each child node underneath the parent node and top-aligned next to the other child nodes. Each node should allow an arbitrary number of child nodes. Ideally, something like this:

[image: grid of boxes]

Notice that this is not the same as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or Isotope, which allow lower images to cross over the edges of higher images. However, the automatic resizing of any number of images is certainly desirable.

As a first try, I've started with this CSS:

```
img.first-row {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
img.second-row {
    max-width: 24%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
img.third-row {
    max-width: 8%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Which only works if you have 1 image in the 1st row, 4 in the 2nd, and 3 in the the 3rd. Furthermore, the third row doesn't really stay underneath the 1st picture of the 2nd row, it just looks that way if you don't have more than 3 pictures.

So there are multiple parts:

1. The recursive nesting of the tree layout, which could hold any content.
2. The automatic resizing of images to fit the layout.
3. The method to accomplish this in an HTML document. I am not particular about Javascript, CSS, jQuery, or whatever. Nor do the images have to fit together especially tightly, as long as the tree layout is maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after sounds like some kind of modified tree map visualisation algorithm. You are right that with Isotope you can't enforce such hierachical layout. Maybe have a [look here on github](https://github.com/lrgalego/jquery-treemap) for a jQuery approach which you could adapt. Probably, [these JavaScript](http://thejit.org/docs/files/Treemap-js.html) libraries are useful. And [this toolkit here](http://prefuse.org/) uses Java and Flash. Or maybe consider [this one](http://www.treemap.com/) which can be deployed on the internet as interactive Java applet.